Is every strict ordering by inclusion a well-ordering?
Given a set $s$ which is transitive and completely ordered by inclusion, that is, such that
$z \in s \rightarrow z \subset s$ and $\left( x \in s \wedge  y \in s \wedge x \neq y \right) \rightarrow 
\left( x \subset y \vee y \subset x \right)$.
Can it be proven, without using the axiom of choice, that $s$ is then well-ordered by inclusion? Use of the axiom of foundation (no unlimited sequence of subsets) would be OK.
I had tried to prove the "a complete order by inclusion is a well-ordering" lemma by the following reasoning:  Suppose some non-empty proper subset $t_1  \subset s$ has no minimal element; then since $t_1$ is not empty, there is some $t_2 \in t$, but then $\{ t_2  \} \subset t_1$. Then if $t_2$ is empty it is a minimal element of $t_1$, contrary to the supposition that $t_1$ has no minimal element. And if $t_2$ has a minimal element $v$, then $v$ is also a minimal element of $t_1$, again contrary to the supposition.  So $t_2$ is also a non-empty proper subset of $t_1$ without a minimal element, and in this way one can form an unlimited sequences of inclusions $s \supset t_1 \supset t_2 \supset t_3 \cdots$ and this violates the axiom of foundation.
However, this "proof" chooses at each step some $t_{i+1} \in t_i$, and this relies on the Axiom of Choice.
I suspect that without the Axiom of Choice one cannot prove that a complete ordering by (transitive) inclusion is a well-ordering.  Indeed, I have seen a definition of an "ordinal" as "a transitive set that is well-ordered by $\in$" -- that would seem to hint that there are other transitive sets that are not well-ordered by $\in$ (thus not well-ordered by $\subset$).
Is that suspicion true?
If so, how does one normally prove that the usual "van Neumann integers" where $0$ is the empty set, $1$ is the set including only $0$, $2$ is the set including  $\{1, 0\}$ and so forth, are well-ordered by inclusion?

${(-\infty,a):a\in\mathbb R}$

A transitive set which is totally ordered by $\in$ must be well-ordered, assuming the Axiom of Foundation. Including "well-ordered" in the definition of an ordinal avoids the need for that axiom.

@user14111 Your first sentence is the very thing I tried to prove (without using the axiom of choice). I was hoping to see how that proof goes.

Suppose $A$ is totally ordered by $\in$. I have to show that a nonempty subset of $A$ has a least element. Suppose $\varnothing\ne S\subseteq A$. By the Axiom of foundation, there is an element $a\in S$ such that $a\cap S=\varnothing$. Then $a$ is the least element of $S$.

Yes, that nails it.  I missed it, by looking at a consequence of the Axiom of Foundation, rather than the axiom itself.
